# How to add alias in laravel eager loading to select query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many-through, eager-loading

I want to optimize my code so I am trying to select only those fields which I actually require into `questionBankOptions`part but the issue is I am getting the error of `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous` so tried to remove this part `select('id as optionId','question_bank_id','option','option_image','correct','status')` which is there in `questionBankOptions` and I didnot see any error. So I cant understand why I am getting this error.

```
$assesmentQuestion = AssesmentQuestion::with([
            'questionBank:id,remarks,question,question_img,question_format',
            'questionCategories',
            'questionBankOptions' => function($q) {
                $q->select('question_bank_options.id as optionId','question_bank_id','option','option_image','correct','status')
                  ->where('status',0);
            }
        ])
        ->select(['id','question_bank_id','preferences','assesment_id'])
        ->where('assesment_id',$id)
        ->orderBy('preferences','ASC')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? The error often gives the full query

Comment: @aynber sure updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query doesn't know which id `'id as optionId'` should be on since `questionBankOptions` apparently uses an inner join. You'll need to specify the table name. I'm going to guess that you want the id from `question_bank_options`, so just add in it like below.

```
$q->select('question_bank_options.id as optionId','question_bank_id',...
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was missing, the table name right, perfect I think I am exhausted forgot this silly thing, need a break. But although a great guess